# Can charmed monsters damage you?

Tags: diablo-iii

If my enchantress follower charms a monster, can that monster's AoE or other attacks harm me if I get in the way?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question the minute my enchantress got that spell. I tried it out with the meteor casting dudes in act IV and I got no damage from walking into a meteor.

My guess is that charmed monsters count as followers the same way as leah or other players. However the enchantress herself can turn you into a chicken right now because of a bug :D